# android - Not just align but cut off image using setPolyToPoly()

Tags: android, image, matrix

There is an objective to transform quadrilateral region (set by 4 points) of image into rectangle image. With [`Matrix.setPolyToPoly()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix#setPolyToPoly(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20int)) and [`Bitmap.createBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean)) I can align whole image so points form a rectangle but now I dont know where is it's left-top corner so I can't cut it off.

For example let's say 4 points are corners of flag *(teal color is just a background of ImageView)*:

[image: example]

Here is code with hardcoded values to fit flag to 72x48 Bitmap.

```
int w = 72;
int h = 48;
float src[] = {108, 201,
               532, 26,
               554, 301,
               55,  372};
float dst[] = {0, 0,
               w, 0,
               w, h,
               0, h};
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, dst.length >> 1);

Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
ImageView iv1 = findViewById(R.id.testImg1);
iv1.setImageBitmap(b1);

Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, 0, b1.getWidth(), b1.getHeight(), m, true);
ImageView iv2 = findViewById(R.id.testImg2);
iv2.setImageBitmap(b2);

//these coordinates are hand-picked
Bitmap b3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b2, 132, 208, w, h);
ImageView iv3 = findViewById(R.id.testImg3);
iv3.setImageBitmap(b3);
```

And original image (be sure you save it to res/drawable-nodpi):

[image: original image]

Comment: @pskink you mean `m.invert(m)`? Something wrong happens: my metod executed correctly but then app is closed. `m.invert(m)` returned `true`.

Comment: but [this](https://codeshare.io/2j76EK) helps

Comment: @pskink, brilliant, post it!

Comment: no, its not brilliant, the base class should be `Drawable` not `BitmapDrawable` but i used it in order to write that class faster...

Comment: @pskink thanks for solution but actually I didn't get why to extend class at all, why not just [this way](https://codeshare.io/aJ86Rn)?

Comment: because you are creating a new extra Bitmap

Comment: @Powercoder What was the reason for this in the end ? I also am seeing this function behave differently than how I would expect in almost the exact same scenario. What is the trick to get it to properly transform the matrix ? It works fine if I am targeting the exact corners of the bitmap... but if I attempt to move a point within the bitmap (not an exact corner) elsewhere... I start getting very strange transformations that don't look right.

Comment: @A.Sanchez.SD, I didn't find out. Moreover, I decided to use `warpPerspective` from OpenCV lib as it works much better: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue) At some configuration of points I used to get broken image or no image at all using android tools, but OpenCV's are fine.

Comment: Hi @Powercoder, what flag you kept on in CMake when trying to generate needed `.so` files and java classes for `warpPerspective` along with `getPerspectiveTransform`? You didn't use the entire SDK published by them did you? That's quite heavy. What was the final `.so` file sizes for you? For me it's getting huge - ~5-6MB for one arch.

Comment: @amar, hi, I don't remember but I have OpenCV folder that is 8 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink didn't post his answer, I do it.

To make new `Bitmap` and save original one - is exactly what I need, so here is solution for me:

```
int w = 72;
int h = 48;
float srcPoints[] = {108, 201,
                         532, 26,
                         554, 301,
                         55,  372};
float dstPoints[] = {0, 0,
                     w, 0,
                     w, h,
                     0, h};
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setPolyToPoly(srcPoints, 0, dstPoints, 0, dstPoints.length >> 1);
Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.macedonia);
Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dstBitmap);
canvas.clipRect(0, 0, w, h);
canvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmap, m, null);
```

But if you don't want to use extra memory, use other approach:

```
class BD extends BitmapDrawable {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    int w = 72;
    int h = 48;
    RectF clip = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);

    public BD(Resources res, int resId) {
        super(res, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId));
        float src[] = {108,201,532,26,554,301,55,372};
        float dst[] = {0,0,w,0,w,h,0,h};
        matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, src.length / 2);
    }

    @Override public int getIntrinsicWidth() {return w;}
    @Override public int getIntrinsicHeight() {return h;}

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipRect(clip);
        canvas.drawBitmap(getBitmap(), matrix, null);
    }
}
```